# Focus box on lightning:input

Tags: lightning, css, slds, inputfield, style

When the input element is 'focused' (currently selected/tabbed) , Chrome puts a blue border around it. And I just can't figure out how I can get this away. I think the browser is putting it there. But I can't get the right style to overwrite it. Any experience with this? Thanks

Code:

```
< lightning:input aura:id="firstName"   value="{!v.something}" class="slds-input slds-input_bare " name="Name" label="First Name" onchange="{!c.doSomething}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blue border is added by the lightning design system on the `slds-input` class like this:

```
.slds-input:focus, .slds-input:active {
    outline: 0;
    border-color: rgb(21, 137, 238); /* This is the blue color of the border */
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #0070d2; /* This is the blue color of the shadow */
}
```

If you want to remove it you can override the color. Here's an example with the default color:

```
.THIS .slds-input:focus, .THIS .slds-input:active {
     border-color: rgb(216, 221, 230);
     box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This should work

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. This solution worked for me.